# Как пользоваться этим куском кода? RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, redbeanphp

```
    $oldToolBox = R::getToolBox();
$oldAdapter = $oldToolBox->getDatabaseAdapter();
$customWriter = new CustomPKWriterMySQL( $oldAdapter );
$newRedBean = new OODB( $customWriter );
$newToolBox = new ToolBox( $newRedBean, $oldAdapter, $customWriter );
R::configureFacadeWithToolbox( $newToolBox );
```

Как этим пользоваться?
Что на что изменить? За что отвечает $oldAdapter, $oldToolBox и все переменные в этом коде, а так же на что их нужно заменять, проблема состоит в том, что я бытался изменить значение в базе данных по u_ud, но т.к у redbean php primary key стоит как id я хочу его изменить этим кодом.

Comment: а собственно какая перед Вами стоит задача Вы можете описать? Чего Вам нужно добитья? `Что на что изменить?` для чего?

Comment: Сделал правку вопроса